# Check for similar words or misspellings

Tags: r, string

I have a big long list of words, and a large dataframe, so whilst I could check this manually for one (as in the example below) I would like to be able to repeat this with any word.

```
CHECK_WORD <- "HELLO"
L <- data.frame(STRINGS <- c("Hello my name is","He llo boyo", "He loved cheese", "Healo", "Monkey", "Ello", "Goodbye Hello"),
                CHECKS  <- c(T,T,F,T,F,T,T)
                )
```

I would like to create a new boolean column (CHECKS) checking if "HELLO" or reasonable misspelling also appears in the string (ignoring case and accounting for spelling errors).

For example it should be able to pick up the first two, but it would not pick up "He loved cheese"  despite the first 5 characters being similar.

I am aware of RegEx but have not used it for something like this. Usually I use prewritten code and modify it very slightly to suit my needs, but would have no idea how to write it for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a way to perfectly match misspelled words is very tricky since the definition of a "valid typo" could be considered a matter of opinion...  There are ways to check the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of words in a data frame like yours, based on a check word.

```
CHECK_WORD <- "HELLO"
L <- data.frame(
  STRINGS = c(
    "Hello my name is",
    "He llo boyo",
    "He loved cheese",
    "Hello",
    "Healo",
    "Monkey",
    "Ello",
    "Goodbye Hello"
  )
)

L$CHECK = CHECK_WORD %>% 
  adist(L$STRINGS,ignore.case = T,partial = T) %>% 
  as.vector()

L
```

output:

```
           STRINGS CHECK
1 Hello my name is     0
2      He llo boyo     1
3  He loved cheese     1
4            Hello     0
5            Healo     1
6           Monkey     4
7             Ello     1
8    Goodbye Hello     0
```

To make this into a function that can be applied to other words and data frames you could do something like this.

```
check_match = function(df,check_column,check_word,max = 1){
  df$CHECK = check_word %>% 
    adist(df[,check_column],ignore.case = T,partial = T) %>% 
    as.vector() %>% 
    {. < max}
  
  return(df)
}

check_match(df = L,check_column = 'STRINGS',check_word = 'Hello')
```

output:

```
           STRINGS CHECK
1 Hello my name is  TRUE
2      He llo boyo FALSE
3  He loved cheese FALSE
4            Hello  TRUE
5            Healo FALSE
6           Monkey FALSE
7             Ello FALSE
8    Goodbye Hello  TRUE
```

As you can see this doesn't meet all your criteria but could be a first step towards what you are looking for.

A potential way to address this could be adding a penalty for spacing, although, in my opinion, this means adding an arbitrary criterium. In the function below, you specify a `penalise_space` which effectively multiplies the number of spaces reaching a closer result to what you were aiming for.

```
check_match = function(df,
                       check_column,
                       check_word,
                       max = 1,
                       ignore.case = TRUE,
                       partial = TRUE,
                       penalise_space = 0) {
  
  if(penalise_space > 0){
    df[,"temp_check_column"] = gsub(x = df[,check_column],pattern = ' ',replacement = paste0(rep(' ',penalise_space),collapse = ''))
  }else{
    df[,"temp_check_column"] = df[,check_column]
  }
  
  df$CHECK = check_word %>% 
    adist(df[,'temp_check_column'],ignore.case = ignore.case,partial = partial) %>% 
    as.vector() %>% 
    {. < max} 
  
  df[,"temp_check_column"] = NULL
  
  return(df)
}
```

test:

```
> check_match(df = L,check_column = 'STRINGS',check_word = 'Hello',penalise_space = 1,max = 2)
           STRINGS CHECK
1 Hello my name is  TRUE
2      He llo boyo  TRUE
3  He loved cheese  TRUE
4            Hello  TRUE
5            Healo  TRUE
6           Monkey FALSE
7             Ello  TRUE
8    Goodbye Hello  TRUE
> check_match(df = L,check_column = 'STRINGS',check_word = 'Hello',penalise_space = 2,max = 2)
           STRINGS CHECK
1 Hello my name is  TRUE
2      He llo boyo FALSE
3  He loved cheese FALSE
4            Hello  TRUE
5            Healo  TRUE
6           Monkey FALSE
7             Ello  TRUE
8    Goodbye Hello  TRUE
```

source: https://statisticsglobe.com/fuzzy-matching-r

Comment: That is perfect. Its very difficult when you have a problem, and an idea how to solve, but not the technical vocabulary to properly search for it! This way I can identify groups of words specific to the search word i.e. "He Loved" and check against a vocabulary list. If all the words are, individually, correctly spelled I can use this in conjunction with the Levenshtein distance to create the boolean.

Comment: I edited now the function to allow for a "spacing penalty" which should generate closer results to your goal.

Comment: Nice function, but always use with care and a funny demonstration: toss in "Hell of a job to do right ;)" which obviously will return TRUE too

Comment: I also made that change. I also did it so that the word it is checking for becomes the title of the new column.